# HTTP connection made in Java fails with too many redirects?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I've got a simple Tomcat-based Java app that functions as a sort of firewall - I take requests from the "outside", reroute them to resources on the "inside", and return the result to the "outside."

This works fine for GETs, but I'm trying to add a POST function for a different request and I cannot get it working.   The "inside" remote server is password protected and I cannot get the remote server to accept the authentication credentials (they work for the GET so the credentials are fine.)  Instead, the Tomcat server calls the Authenticator over and over, and finally fails. Here's the error I'm getting:

```
    java.net.ProtocolException: Server redirected too many  times (20)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1848)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1441)
        at com.mystuff.house.server.MyServlet.doPost(MyServlet.java:191)
```

I'm sure I'm doing something stupid, but I can't see where it is.   Here's the guts of the servlet doPost() routine:

```
        URL url = new URL("HTTP", "10.10.1.101", -1, "/myresource");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection http = (HttpURLConnection) con;
        http.setRequestMethod("POST");
        http.setDoOutput(true);
        String encoded = String.valueOf(Base64.getEncoder().encode((a.getUsername().concat(":").concat(a.getPassword())).getBytes()));
        http.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic "+encoded);
        http.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8");

        // Read the POST payload from the front end post, write to back end post
        InputStream r = request.getInputStream();
        OutputStream os = http.getOutputStream();
        int j = 0;
        while ((j = r.read()) != -1) {
            os.write((byte) j);
        }

        http.connect();

        // Try reading the result from the back end, push it back to the front end
        try {
            InputStream i = http.getInputStream();
            OutputStream o = response.getOutputStream();

            // read/write bytes until EOF
            j = 0;
            while ((j = i.read()) != -1) {
                o.write((byte) j);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("AIEEEE!  Error receiving page from HTTP call");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: This is a problem at the server end, not with this client code, unless there is something wrong with the authorization.

Comment: @EJP It did turn out to be a problem with the authentication.   The specific URL I was hitting required a different password.   The remote server never sent back a 401 or a 403, which is what I would have expected.     If you want to post your comment as an answer, I'll be happy to mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this, after some investigation, turned out to be that the authentication was not valid for the specific URL that I was trying to hit on the remote server.

I had expected to get a 403, 401 or 407 back from the remote server but that never happened, instead this "redirect" happened.   So that's something to be aware of if you are trying to hit password-protected URLs from Java code.